# hover with fixed random color in the same div

Tags: html, jquery

I use JQuery to have a hover with random colors, with this code I can have several colors in the same div if I move the mouse.

My goal is to have only one fixed color in the same div each time, if the mouse doesn't leave the div the color must stay the same ?

Do you have an idea please ?

```js
    $(document).ready(function(){
  
  $('.box').mouseover(function(){
        var back = ["#B98B91","#A5465F","#A31E64","#F4C181","#F28C54","#F39131"];
        var color = back[Math.floor(Math.random() * back.length)];
        $('.box').css("background-color", color);
  });
  
  });
```

```css
.box {border:solid;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box">
<p>BLA BLA BLA</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you want to keep the color when the mouse cursor leaves `.box`?

Comment: No I want to keep a single color even if I move the mouse in the same div, when I leave the color will disappear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to use this event listener. `mouseenter`

See: [mouseover](https://api.jquery.com/mouseover/), [mouseenter](https://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var back = ["#B98B91", "#A5465F", "#A31E64", "#F4C181", "#F28C54", "#F39131"],
    color;

  $('.box').mouseenter(function() {
    color = back[Math.floor(Math.random() * back.length)];
    $('.box').css("background-color", color);
  });

  $('.box').mouseleave(function() {
    $('.box').css("background-color", "white");
  });

});
```

```css
.box {
  border: solid;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box">
  <p>BLA BLA BLA</p>
</div>
```

Comment: From OP `if the mouse doesn't leave the div the color must stay the same` your code leaves the color in even when mouse leaves

Comment: @Huangism Yes, when mouse out, I didn't realize he wanted it to be clean. Now behaves as intended.